# :focus in jQuery

Tags: jquery, focus

Why does this not work and how do I do this correctly

```
if ($('#ch03').is(':focus')) {
  $('this').attr("aria-grabbed","true");
} else {
  $('this').attr("aria-grabbed","false");
}
```

or based on existing SO solution which I can't get to work

```
var inFocus = false;
$('#ch03').focus(function() {
    $('#ch03').attr("aria-grabbed","true");
});

$('#ch03').blur(function() {
    $('#ch03').attr("aria-grabbed","false");
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="activity_contents">
<div id="columns" class="clearfix">
<div id="col_1" class="column">
<div class="column_head">Section A</div>
  <ul id="tier1" class="connected" role="region" aria-labelledby="col_1" aria-dropeffect="move">
  </ul>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div id="col_2" class="column">
<div class="column_head">Section  B</div>
  <ul id="tier2" class="connected" role="region" aria-labelledby="col_2" aria-dropeffect="move">
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="col_3" class="column">
<div class="column_head">Section C</div>
  <ul id="tier3" class="connected" role="region" aria-labelledby="col_3" aria-    dropeffect="move">
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="col_4" class="column last">
<div class="column_head">Section  D </div>
  <ul id="tier4" class="connected" role="region" aria-labelledby="col_4" aria-dropeffect="move">
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="well" class="clearfix">
  <ul id="choices" class="connected" aria-labelledby="well" role="region">
    <li id="ch01" class="choice"><a href="#">Drag item 1</a></li>
    <li id="ch03" class="choice"><a href="#">Drag item 2</a></li>
    <li id="ch04" class="choice"><a href="#">Drag item 3</a></li>
    <li id="ch02" class="choice"><a href="#">Drag item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help on this one. THe code is from the jQueriUI dragnDrop/Sortable. What I am trying to achieve is to make this more accessible by dynamically adding aria-roles.

Comment: this refers to the element, there is no such element called 'this' . remove quotes around this

Comment: Thanks DinoMyte but still does not add the attribute on focus

Comment: what type of element is `'#ch03'` is??
is it a div or a form element (text, select, etc..)

because this method works with text, select but not with div

Comment: not really. focus is supported by any element in DOM as long as it supports the tabIndex functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1 :** Relys on the `click` event on the DOM which checks if the element has focus then set the attribute `aria-grabbed` value.

```
$(document).on("click",function(){
  $("#ch03").attr("aria-grabbed",$("#ch03").is(':focus'));
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/2oygeh0w

**Option 2 :** Simply triggers the `focus` and `blur` event on the element to set the attribute '`aria-grabbed`' value.

```
 $("#ch03").on("focus",function(){
      $(this).attr("aria-grabbed",true);
    }).on("blur",function()
    {
      $(this).attr("aria-grabbed",false);
    });;
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/2oygeh0w/1/

**UPDATE** : Based on the html you posted, if you are trying to set the attribute 'aria-grabbed' on each li on focus.

```
$('#choices li a').on("focus",function(e)
{
     $(this).closest('li').attr("aria-grabbed",true);
     $(this).addClass("selected");   

}).on("blur",function(e)
{
       $(this).closest('li').attr("aria-grabbed",false);
      $(this).removeClass("selected");
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/2oygeh0w/3/

Comment: Thanks DinoMyte but not working. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Could you add your html to the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Using DinoMyte's method and some code from sitepoint website
http://www.sitepoint.com/accessible-drag-drop/

/*****
Test

****/

```
//get the collection of draggable targets and add their draggable attribute
for(var 
    targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-draggable="target"]'), 
    len = targets.length, 
    i = 0; i < len; i ++)
{
    targets[i].setAttribute('aria-dropeffect', 'none');
}

//get the collection of draggable items and add their draggable attributes
for(var 
    items = document.querySelectorAll('[data-draggable="item"]'), 
    len = items.length, 
    i = 0; i < len; i ++)
{
    items[i].setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
    items[i].setAttribute('aria-grabbed', 'false');
    items[i].setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
}
//Place some dynamic aria roles for accessibility
$("#ch01").on("focus",function(){
  $(this).attr("aria-grabbed",true);
}).on("blur",function()
{
  $(this).attr("aria-grabbed",false);
});
$("#ch02").on("focus",function(){
  $(this).attr("aria-grabbed",true);
}).on("blur",function()
{
  $(this).attr("aria-grabbed",false);
});
$("#ch03").on("focus",function(){
  $(this).attr("aria-grabbed",true);
}).on("blur",function()
{
  $(this).attr("aria-grabbed",false);
});
$("#ch04").on("focus",function(){
  $(this).attr("aria-grabbed",true);
}).on("blur",function()
{
  $(this).attr("aria-grabbed",false);
});

//end
```

Still needs to be cleaned up but the idea works. One step at a time and I'll get there with your help :-)

Comment: What you posted is completed different from what you are looking for. Are you looking for drag drop functionality ?

Comment: The objective, and sorry for being all over the place, is to have a drag and drop function that is keyboard accessible. There are 4 dragable items and 4 drop zones. Once the user has drag/dropped the items into the posible zones they click a check button which tells/shows the user which were correct and which were wrong. The user get 3 tries. On the last (third) check the items are moved to the correct drop zone and the user is alerted which were originally right and which were wrong and the now correct position. Yeah I know a bit complicated.